# how to access objects inside static cells?

Tags: swift

I have about 30 static cells! each has textLabel and 2 UIImageView! How do I get to the right UIImageView when I click on a particular cell?

Target: I need to take a photo when I click on the cell and put this photo in the corresponding UIImageView inside the cell.

Comment: You can just add outlets for all of those labels and image views. But, frankly, if you’ve got that many and they all have text label and two image views, you might want to reconsider the choice to use static cells. Using dynamic cell prototypes are perfect for the scenario where the cells share some common look, feel, and interaction pattern. In short, is there a reason why you’ve used static cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you have custom static `UITableViewCells`. You can set the `UIImageView`'s and `UILabel`'s tag property from storyboard to a number different from 0 (and different between them, of course) and access it using `viewWithTag(_:)` method.

Inside `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` method:

```
let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(imageViewTag) as! UIImageView
```

and the same for the other views you want to access.

Comment: All I did was choose a static table in the storyboard! need something else? because now I don't have the "cell" function from your example

Comment: If you are using a `UITableViewController` (which I think is the only one that supports static cells, but I may be wrong) then you can implement the mentioned method. If you are using a simple `UIViewController` then it should conform to `UITableViewDelegate` and then you can implement this method. You can take the cell using `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)`. In the second case, make sure you set the `tableView`'s delegate your view controller, so it calls that method when you tap a cell.